# USB Audio Interface not recognized

Tags: input-device, usb-audio

I've got an IKMultimedia IRig Pro Connected to PI4B
It appears in Jack under ALSA-MIDI but I can't find the System-Audio Input

Running `lsusb` shows me

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bf8:1028 Fujitsu Siemens Computers 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1963:000a  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:3431 VIA Labs, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`dmesg` says

```
[    1.226824] systemd[1]: Detected architecture arm.
[    1.236156] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <raspberrypi>.
[    1.298834] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    1.445493] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=1963, idProduct=000a, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    1.445511] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    1.445524] usb 1-1.1: Product: iRig PRO
[    1.445536] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: IK Multimedia
[    1.454129] usbhid 1-1.1:1.0: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint
[    1.578745] usb 1-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    1.728163] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0bf8, idProduct=1028, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    1.728178] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber
```

`cat /proc/asound/cards` says

```
 0 [ALSA           ]: bcm2835_alsa - bcm2835 ALSA
                      bcm2835 ALSA
 1 [PRO            ]: USB-Audio - iRig PRO
                      IK Multimedia iRig PRO at usb-0000:01:00.0-1.1, full speed
```

When I press the right mouse button on the volume button at the taskbar, I can Use iRig Pro as an output device but opening the volume settings there are no tabs for input devices, maybe because there are no input devices?

I tried adding `dwc_otg.speed=1` to my `/boot/cmdline.txt` file as this should help on usb 1.1 DAC issues but no luck.

`alsa-base.conf` is empty at the moment

running `alsamixer` lets me select iRig Pro as Soundcard with F6 but it just says this device has no controls.

Any Idea to get this working?

Comment: Are you sure the device connected is supported by Raspberry Pi 4? https://cgi.ikmultimedia.com/ikforum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=19889&start=75

Comment: Not really - it was just the only usb audio device I got at my place right now so I was giving it a try.

Comment: I'm sure it's supported for rpi3 but not sure about rpi4. If you have another rpi rather than rpi4, evaluate your procedures. Hope you find the solution.

Comment: Sadly its my first and only Pi anyway will try to find a solution